# Force Telerik Grid to use GET in AJAX data binding

Tags: c#, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have following code in an old application that uses Telerik Grid. The ajax request to the server is always using POST. I need to change it to GET, but I can't find any documentation since it is an older version (not Kendo Grid, just Telerik Grid). Any ideas how to fix that?

```
Html.Telerik().Grid<GridDataRow>()
          .Name("gridRecipientList")
          .Columns(columns => ...)                                       
          .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
             dataBinding.Ajax().Select("MyAction", "MyController"))
          .Pageable(settings => ...)
          .PrefixUrlParameters(false)
          .EnableCustomBinding(true)
          .Sortable(sorting => sorting
             .SortMode(Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.GridSortMode.SingleColumn)
             .OrderBy(order=>order.Add(f=>f.P1)))
          .Scrollable(settings => settings.Height(300))
          .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
```

Comment: It's been a while since I've used that control, but personally I think it would be easier to modify your controller to accept a POST than trying to find documentation for a deprecated user control library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer in hope that it helps someone else. I could define a client-side handler and explicitly set the verb used for read operation:

```
var onGridLoaded = function (e) {
  var telerikGridData = $("div#gridRecords").data('tGrid');
  if (telerikGridData != null) {
    telerikGridData.ajax.options.transport.read.type = "GET";
  }
};
```

And to bind the this function to the grid I added this to the server-side code above:

```
.ClientEvents(events => {
  events.OnGridLoaded("onGridLoaded");
 })
```